# Why are some packages inaccessible in Xamarin Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, package, using

I've inherited a Xamarin Android app, and I'm not fully familiar with the way it works. For a class I'm creating, I want to use the packages `Android.Content` and `System.Environment`, however neither are available (when I start typing they don't show up in the code completion dropdown).

I'm wondering what determines the available packages for an application, and how to make more available?

Comment: they both should be available - it might be an Intellisense issue.  If you use "var string = System.Environment.Newline;" does it compile?

Comment: @Jason, no it doesn't compile, it shows an error on missing packages. The strange thing is that I have another project that uses these packages and it works fine. I just can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it took me a while to find this information, even though it's probably common knowledge.

To add packages, in Xamarin, right-click on the "References" directory under your project and select "Manage References". Then from this dialog, select whatever package that you need to add.